# Spring RESTful Web Service with JSON gives HTTP 406 error code

Tags: json, spring, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 3.2.5 to create a RESTful web service. To implement it I've used `@ResponseBody` tag. When I use `InternalResourceViewResolver` and try to load Html response then it is working fine. But when I call a URL which is marked as `@ResponseBody` then it gives *HTTP 406* error code with error text as

> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.

I have included Jackson jar files in my lib directory as well.

Here is my controller method which handles service request.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping (value = "/resp.htm")
public Data jsonResp() {
    Data d = new Data();

    d.setName("TEst");
    d.setAddr("Address....");

    return d;
}
```

There are lots of questions have been asked & answered, I've tried many of them, but it still gives the same result. Then I came across a new kind of answer, which was stating to use `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`. By using it I am able to view response in intended format. That is JSON format.

After using `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`, servlet dispatcher code looks like this:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </map>
    </property>

    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <!-- JSON View -->
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="2" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

So, my question is, whenever we require to use Spring's Web Service feature, do we must require to have `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`?

Answer (score 2):

Add [gson](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.10)  in your class path. as well as [jackson](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.2.2)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue while calling a spring rest service from angular 8 for uploading a file. I was using ResponseEntity to encapsulate the success or failure message for which I was having the 406 response. all I did was in the UI side this.httpClient.post(url, formData,{responseType: 'text'}) and I was able accept the string as response from the service response.

Answer (score 0):

The annotation `@ResponseBody` used with custom class types, generally uses `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to convert the object to JSON and return it in `application/json` content.

Since your request doesn't contain an `Accept` header for `application/json`, Spring deems the content it's creating as unacceptable and instead returns a 406.

You could simply change your request to add the `Accept` header. (You can't do this easily in a browser).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the request had `.html` suffix and received this error. Once removed, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to add `jackson` libraries to your classpath find them [Here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)