# Spring Webservices gives 406 error

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

I have created a simple Spring with webservices example but when I try to get the response I am getting error as :

**HTTP Status 406 -**

> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating
>   responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request
>   "accept" headers.

This is my Spring controller:

```
@Controller
public class DataController {

    @RequestMapping("studentlist")
    public @ResponseBody
    List<Student> getStudentList() {
        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        studentList.add(new Student(2, "A1", "B1", "a@gmail.com", "123456"));
        studentList.add(new Student(3, "A2", "B2", "b@gmail.com", "123456"));
        studentList.add(new Student(4, "A3", "B3", "c@gmail.com", "123456"));

        return studentList;
    }
}
```

This is my `Student.java` file:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Student {

    int id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String email;
    String mobileNumber;

// Setters & Getters
}
```

My Spring web configuration file has below entry:

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.web.controller" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="xml" value="text/xml" />                
            <entry key="htm" value="text/html" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html" />
      <property name="defaultViews">
    <list>
      <!-- JSON View -->
      <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView">
      </bean>

      <!-- JAXB XML View -->
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
               <property name="classesToBeBound">
                <list>
                   <value>com.web.domain.Student</value>
                </list>
               </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
      </bean>
     </list>
  </property>
  <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />    

</bean>
```

As per this settings I understand that if my URL ends with `.json` I will get JSON response. If it ends with `.xml`, I will get XML response. Similarly if the URL ends with `.htm`, I  will get an html response.

If I hit the URL as `http://localhost:8080/spring-ws/studentlist.json` then I am getting JSON response successfully.

Now if my URL us `http://localhost:8080/spring-ws/studentlist.xml` or `http://localhost:8080/spring-ws/studentlist.htm`, then I am getting below error message:

> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating
>   responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request
>   "accept" headers.

Can you please help me in fixing this issue?

Also what is the use of `ignoreAcceptHeader` property in my code? Is that required always?

I have referred to this SO post : [Spring RESTful Web Service with JSON gives HTTP 406 error code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544143/spring-restful-web-service-with-json-gives-http-406-error-code)

As given in above post, I have already tried to set the `Accept` header as `application/xml` and `text/html` while submitting the request using Chrome PostMan client but still I see same issue.

Comment: Look into content negotiation.

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2013/06/03/content-negotiation-using-views explains that `ignoreAcceptHeader` is useful when you're using the path extension to determine content type

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, Can you please tell where the issue is? Now I am clear on `ignoreAcceptHeader` part based on Jim comments but I am not able to figure out where I made mistake in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to return a `List` of `Student` objects in your controller.

So, create a wrapper class with JAXB annotations and use that wrapper class while returning from your controller to fix the issue.

For example, create the class like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class WrapperList<T> {

    private List<T> list;

    public WrapperList() {
        list = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public WrapperList(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @XmlAnyElement
    public List<T> getItems() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

and return this in your class:

```
@RequestMapping("studentlist")
    public 
    WrapperList<Student> getStudentList() {
        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        // add students to the list and put them in wrapper class 
        WrapperList<Student> list = new WrapperList<Student>(studentList);
        return list;
    }
```

Also you can keep your configuration simple like this:

```
 <beans>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.web.controller" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                <entry key="xml" value="text/xml" />
                <entry key="htm" value="text/html" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html" />
        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this [example](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-contentnegotiatingviewresolver-example/) is more along the lines of what you want.  In the controller instead of @ResponseBody and the actual java object as a return type they return a String for the view name ("pizza") in the controller.

Comment: Thanks Jim, but the example given in your link is different, I am not able to get what needs to be changed in my code to fix the issue.